# Copy a certain type of files from 98 subfolders to 98 folders in an external directory with matlab

Tags: matlab, file, directory, copy

I have a parent directory with 97 folders. These folders' name end with three digits and are the following: `['Sub_001', 'Sub_002', 'Sub_003', 'Sub_004', 'Sub_005', 'Sub_006', 'Sub_008', 'Sub_009', 'Sub_010', 'Sub_011', 'Sub_012', 'Sub_013', 'Sub_014', 'Sub_016', 'Sub_018', 'Sub_019', 'Sub_022', 'Sub_024', 'Sub_028', 'Sub_029', 'Sub_031', 'Sub_033', 'Sub_034', 'Sub_035', 'Sub_036', 'Sub_037', 'Sub_102', 'Sub_103', 'Sub_104', 'Sub_105', 'Sub_107', 'Sub_110', 'Sub_111', 'Sub_112', 'Sub_113', 'Sub_114', 'Sub_116', 'Sub_117', 'Sub_118', 'Sub_119', 'Sub_120', 'Sub_121', 'Sub_122', 'Sub_123', 'Sub_201', 'Sub_202', 'Sub_203', 'Sub_205', 'Sub_206', 'Sub_207', 'Sub_208', 'Sub_209', 'Sub_210', 'Sub_211', 'Sub_212', 'Sub_213', 'Sub_214', 'Sub_215', 'Sub_216', 'Sub_217', 'Sub_218', 'Sub_219', 'Sub_301', 'Sub_302', 'Sub_303', 'Sub_304', 'Sub_305', 'Sub_306', 'Sub_308', 'Sub_309', 'Sub_310', 'Sub_312', 'Sub_313', 'Sub_315', 'Sub_316', 'Sub_317', 'Sub_318', 'Sub_319', 'Sub_320', 'Sub_321', 'Sub_322', 'Sub_323', 'Sub_324', 'Sub_325', 'Sub_326', 'Sub_328', 'Sub_329', 'Sub_330', 'Sub_331', 'Sub_332', 'Sub_333', 'Sub_334', 'Sub_335', 'Sub_336', 'Sub_337', 'Sub_338', 'Sub_339']`.

Each of these 97 folder has many different subfolders, one of which is called "MNI_TC". In the "MNI_TC" subfolder there are many files starting with "wCovDeriv_s6rf", among others.
Any advice on a matlab code to create a list of 97 empty target folders with the same names as the 97 folders above in a certain target directory?

Then, how can I copy all the files starting with "wCovDeriv_s6rf" from each of the 97 folders, in the corresponding target folder with the same name of the folder from which the "wCovDeriv_s6rf" files came from? Each target folder needs to have all the "wCovDeriv_s6rf" files from the folder that had the same three digits in its name.

I tried the code below, but it generated only a folder in each of the 97 folders, I need it in an external directory of my choice.

```matlab
% Define the parent directory
parentDir = '...';


% Define the target directory
targetDir = '...'; 

% Loop over all 98 subfolders of the parent directory
for i = 1:98
    
    % Define the current source directory
    currSourceDir = fullfile(parentDir, sprintf('%03d', i), 'MNI_TC');
    
    % Define the current target directory
    currTargetDir = fullfile(targetDir, sprintf('%03d', i));
    
    % Create the target directory if it does not already exist
    if ~exist(currTargetDir, 'dir')
        mkdir(currTargetDir);
    end
    
    % Define the file name to search for
    fileName = 'wCovDeriv_s6rf*';
    
    % Find all files matching the file name in the current source directory
    fileList = dir(fullfile(currSourceDir, fileName));
    
    % Loop over all files found in the current source directory
    for j = 1:numel(fileList)
        
        % Get the file name
        currFileName = fileList(j).name;
        
        % Define the source file path
        currSourceFilePath = fullfile(currSourceDir, currFileName);
        
        % Define the target file path
        currTargetFilePath = fullfile(currTargetDir, currFileName);
        
        % Copy the file from the source directory to the target directory
        copyfile(currSourceFilePath, currTargetFilePath);
        
    end
    
end
```

Comment: I would add some `disp` statements to see the values of `currSourceFilePath` and `currTargetFilePath` (the old-fashioned debugging method), and also look at the return values of `copyfile` (`[status,msg] = copyfile(...)`), which will tell you if it actually copied something or not, and what the error was if it didn't.

Comment: Of course, `sprintf('%03d', i)` doesn't match your directory names, it should be `sprintf('Sub_%03d', i)`, but also the numbers are not consecutive. Why not try `dir(fullfile(parentDir, 'Sub_*', 'MNI_TC'))`, and iterate over the result?